# 'Error: Cannot find module' from relative path in Typescript

Tags: typescript, ts-node

My `index.ts` file imports a class from a `bindings.d.ts` file, but I'm getting `Error: Cannot find module '../bindings'` at run-time with no compile-time errors from TS.

My `bindings.d.ts`:

```
export class MyClass {
  sayHello(): string;
}
```

My `index.ts`:

```
import { MyClass } from "../bindings";

console.log(MyClass);
```

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "typeRoots": [
        "@types",
        "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
  }
}
```

My file tree:

```
- src
  - index.ts
- bindings.d.ts
- tsconfig.json
- node_modules
- @types
```

When running `ts-node src/index.ts`, I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../bindings'
Require stack:
- /Users/slider/Desktop/myProject/src/index.ts
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/slider/Desktop/myProject/src/index.ts:4:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1043:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1046:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
```

I've also tried adding `"ts-node": { "files": true }` to `tsconfig.json` but to no avail. What am I missing?

Comment: You cannot import from a `d.ts` file as a module as they can't provide executable code. `d.ts` files are usually accompanying existing JavaScript code, adding type definitions. If you had a `bindings.js`, it should work (importing the code from `js` and teh typings from `d.ts`). Or you could change the file extension to `bindings.ts` and add a function implementation

Comment: Aren't `.d.ts` files with an import line treated as normal modules? I assumed `bindings.d.ts` could be imported as any other module in `index.ts` as long as it imported something else.

Comment: You might be able to import type definitions from them, but what is supposed to happen if you call `(new MyClass()).sayHello()`? `d.ts` files cannot offer an implementation like `ts` files can

Comment: But you might be right that your problem is a different one. `tsc` and I assume `ts-node` as well expect all files to be in your `rootDir`, otherwise they won't know where to put their compiled versions in the `dist dir`